# I want to wait the result from other class - objective c

Tags: objective-c, loops, grand-central-dispatch

I have in my A Class an if statement.

In class A:

```
        if (support_zrtp){
           // Do something

        } else if (support_zrtp && passThreeWays){
            // Do something



        } else {
               // Do something


        }
```

and Class B ì, I take the value from XML.but I take it very late, after my function  callURI finished.

```
  if ([_zrtp_support boolValue]){ 
// support_zrtp true or false 
}
```

and the value of support_zrtp come form B Class which first take the value from Server and then pass to me. the problem is, I want to wait until correct value come from server then use it.

I tried to use  **dispatch_semaphore_wait** but when I use it, all my code stop and not work any more in this case also stop to receive value from server. 
I appreciate any solution.

Comment: Do you realize that the code guarded by `else if (support_zrtp && passThreeWays)` will never execute?  (That is, if `support_zrtp ` is true it takes the first path, otherwise the third.)

Comment: Thanks @Phillip Mills, that is not important for now, I need the solution for the value to arrive on time

Answer (score 1):

You can use a completion handler which is like function that will be called once an action is finished

That would mean that you can even do some work in another thread but please always remember to run any ui update on the main thread

an example to do so would be

```
- (void) startChecking
{
   [self checkSupport:@"" data:[NSData init] completion:^(BOOL support_zrtp, BOOL passThreeWays) {

      // checking has finished 
      if (support_zrtp && passThreeWays){
         // do something

      } else if (support_zrtp){
         // Do Something

      } else {
         // do something


      }
   }];
}

- (void)checkSupport:(NSString *)stringValue data:(NSData *)data completion:(void (^)(BOOL support_zrtp, BOOL passThreeWays))completion
{
   // do some work to check

   completion(true, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zombie, do you have any idea how to use  dispatch_semaphore_wait instead of completion handler

Comment: Thanks @zombie, Good idea but there is one problem, - (void)checkSupport function, what I have to do because I already sent to the server the request, the only things I need to wait, I have to check again with server with - (void)checkSupport?

Comment: can you show some more code so i would help you to place everything?